# When does a Ruby on Rails attribute get its methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I added an attribute to a Ruby on Rails data model (Client), with a migration. I added the attribute (veteran) to the model, in the attr_accessible statement. I ran the migration, so that the attribute shows up in db/schema.rb. I added the attribute to the spec/factories factory for that particular object.

In the view for the model, I have something like this:

```
<td><%= f.label :veteran %></td>

<% if @client.veteran %>

<td><%= f.radio_button :veteran, :true, :checked => true %>Yes</td>

<td><%= f.radio_button :veteran, :false %>No</td>

<% else %>

<td><%= f.radio_button :veteran, :true %>Yes</td>

<td><%= f.radio_button :veteran, :false, :checked => true %>No</td>

<% end %>
```

My question is this: even though in the controller, in new, I did
Client.new,
the 
statement @client.veteran gives an error:
NoMethodError: undefined method veteran in @client

Why doesn't the ActiveRecord knowledge of veteran get into the Client object? How do I avoid this error?
(I should also add that the problem does not occur in Rspec and Cucumber, in the automated testing.)

UPDATE. I now understand that I need

```
 attr_accessor :veteran
```

but I don't understand why other attributes seem to be OK in "attr_accessible" (for whitelisting) but not this one (which is new).

Steve Turczyn, the controller code is just @client = Client.new. I am pretty sure that was the error I saw.
I clearly need to understand attr_accessor vs. attr_accessible much better.

Comment: "undefined method veteran in @client" ?  That's not what the message actually said.  Can you post the exact error?  And perhaps your controller code for the ClientController `new` method.

Comment: Please show the exact error, and show the veteran attribute in your model method or relationship looks like.  Posting your controller code would help too.

Comment: have you tried restarting the web server? just to make sure it reloaded the models?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `attr_accessor` in an `ActiveRecord::Base`, Rails automatically does that for you for all the fields in the schema.

Also your view needs only this:

```
<td><%= f.label :veteran %></td>

<td><%= f.radio_button :veteran, :true, checked: @client.veteran? %>Yes</td>

<td><%= f.radio_button :veteran, :false, checked: !@client.veteran? %>No</td>
```

As for your question about

> When does a Ruby on Rails attribute get its methods?

The answer is that after you run the migration you already have access to attributes created in it. If there is an error like that, restart the server but it should not be necessary.